# How to recover pages from site with only ftp?

Tags: pages

I have lost http access to my site and i need to recover pages from it. Is there a way?

Comment: the answer is on your question. What's the problem with ftp?

Comment: @peteroak how do i do it? what file do i download?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your `pages` are stored in a database. So they are likely to be safe.

It sounds like something else is broken with your site ...  please can you cut n paste any error message here

**What were you doing to break it?**
1. If you recently updated a plugin or a theme then use your FTP client and login to your directory on your webhost

1. go through your directories looking for wp-content/themes or wp-content/plugins
   (if you just updated a plugin then rename that folder to old_plugins)
2. this will deactivate all plugins and you should be able to go to your website at mywebsite.com/wp-admin

Comment: I figured out that I had to use the phpMyAdmin from the server's control panel to access the pages.